# Stop Appending Elements When Drag is Called

Tags: d3.js

I have a simple document where the user creates rects at current mouse coordinates. From this point, the user can then drag the rects to a new position. Like this:

```
var svg = d3.select('body')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width',800)
    .attr('height',800)
    .on('click',function() {return draw_rect(d3.mouse(this))});

function draw_rect(position) {
svg.append('rect')
    .attr('height',100)
    .attr('width',150)
    .attr('x',(position[0]-75))
    .attr('y',(position[1]-50))
    .attr('opacity',.3)
    .attr('fill','lightgray')
    .attr('stroke','darkgray')
    .call(dragObject);
}

var dragObject = d3.behavior.drag()
    .on('dragstart', function() {
        d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
    })
    .on('drag', function() {
        d3.select(this).attr('x',(d3.mouse(this)[0]-75).attr('y',(d3.mouse(this)[1]-50)
    });
```

The problem is, whenever the drag completes, another rect is appended. And logically, that makes sense, a drag is just like a slow click. Not sure how to fix this at all. I was thinking about adding a bool, but I couldn't think of one that would fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing this in your `click` event:

```
.on('click', function() {
    if (d3.event.defaultPrevented) return;
    draw_rect(d3.mouse(this))
});
```

Besides that, you don't need the `return`: just call `draw_rect`.

Here is your updated code:

```js
var svg = d3.select('body')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', 800)
  .attr('height', 800)
  .on('click', function() {
    if (d3.event.defaultPrevented) return;
    draw_rect(d3.mouse(this))
  });

function draw_rect(position) {
  svg.append('rect')
    .attr('height', 100)
    .attr('width', 150)
    .attr('x', (position[0] - 75))
    .attr('y', (position[1] - 50))
    .attr('opacity', .8)
    .attr('fill', 'lightgray')
    .attr('stroke', 'darkgray')
    .call(dragObject);
}

var dragObject = d3.behavior.drag()
  .on('dragstart', function() {
    d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
  })
  .on('drag', function() {
    d3.select(this).attr('x', d3.mouse(this)[0] - 75).attr('y', d3.mouse(this)[1] - 50)
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```